# Does Dell Poweredge SC1425 need proprietary memory?

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge

We have a Dell Poweredge SC1425 which we're trying to upgrade to serve as an emergency backup, and having no luck finding memory that works with it. The 2gb that's in there works fine - it's when we try and replace it with new memory we hit problems.

First time around we used the Crucial Memory selector tool and got some DDR2 CL3 ECC PC2-5300 memory (4 x 2gb). Didn't work - Ram beep on start up - so we looked more closely at the Dell specs and got some PC2-3200 instead. Same problem. The old Ram still works when we put that back in.

We're a bit stumped. The last choice is to buy some Ram direct from Dell, but it's a lot more expensive (and we're not sure the server is really worth the expense - we could get a new basic server for not much more). But have we missed something?

Edit: yes, the ram we bought is dual rank.

Answer (score 2):

For 2GB sticks, they should be Registered ECC PC2-3200 Dual Rank. If what you got matches that you're probably SOL and what Dell will sell you will fail in the same manner. If you didnt use all 4 slots previously it's also possible that the motherboard is fauly.

Anders

Answer (score 1):

Both the [Cricual](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=PowerEdge%20SC1425&pl=Dell&cat=RAM) and [Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/SC1425/en/ug/f3593aa0.htm#wp1053748) sites say that this should work up to 4Gb Dimms, for a maximum of 16Gb of ram. The required memory is

DDR2 PC2-5300 • CL=5 • Registered • ECC • DDR2-667

Comment: I'd just order it from Crucial as they guarantee compatibility, if it doesn't work just give it back to them.

Answer (score 1):

[Kingston KVR400D2D8R3K2/4](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134273)

We run this on our SC1425s on an 2003 Server with SQL Server for 4 years without issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory supported by SC1425:**

1GB ECC Module  1024MB-400MHz DDR2-400 PC2-3200, 240p DIMM, ECC, Registered, 1.8v
677ms-677

2GB ECC Module  2048MB-400MHz DDR2-400 PC2-3200, 240p DIMM, ECC, Registered, 1.8v
678ms-678

4GB ECC Module  4196MB-400MHz DDR2-400 PC2-3200, 240p DIMM, ECC, Registered, 1.8v
690ms-690

Answer (score 0):

Check out kingston.com and search up your server there, they sell modules that are certified to work (much cheaper than original RAM from your server vendor).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problems, 2x1 GB works fine, when I try to use 2x2Gb it fails when the server starts: blue screen.
It seems to be related to Windows 2003 Server Standard, that allows for max. 4Gb only.
I've tried it with 2x1 Gb original memory (333 Mhz) and additional 2x1 Gb (400 Mhz), but it keeps failing.

It seems there's something fissy with the Windows configuration in combination with the Dell Server.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried updating the bios to the latest version?